# Find who execute the full table scan in mysql

Tags: mysql

In mysql , we have sys.x$statements_with_full_table_scans, that inform us about the full scan.

But I have a lot of erp users that execute many scripts and I don't have a good software to monitoring my application.

My question is.

Anyone have a script that list full scan scripts with list the users that executed those?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL Server doesn't know which client script was responsible for a given query. It might even have been a query run interactively by a user in a MySQL client tool.

You can use `show processlist` once you know the queries that result in full scans, and if you see the bad query, look at the `User` and `Host` to identify the user (assuming each human user has a distinct MySQL username).

Then ask to do a code search for that query in that user's script(s).

---

In Oracle database, the process detail includes the `program` that is the client that opened that session. Example: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_process_detail.htm

But MySQL's protocol does not have that information. The client does not send the name of the client program, so the MySQL Server does not know it.